# Why is the data in the "addtocart()" function not written into the file ? c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

In this program I'm trying to add data about customers in a file. However, for some reason when I open the file I can only see the data from the "newcustomer()" function. Can somebody tell me the reason for this please.
Here's the related part of my code:

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <fstream>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;
    
        struct cartitem{
            string name;
            int num_of_copies;
            float price;};
        int i;
        int ci=0;
        fstream customersdata;

        void newcustomer(fstream &customersdata, string cname){
            string arrtime;
            customersdata << "Name: " << cname << '\n';
            string order = cname+"order";
            customersdata << order <<'\n';}
        
        void addtocart(fstream &customersdata, string cname){
            ci++;
            string bname;
            cout << "enter book name \n" ; cin >> bname;
            int num_of_copies;
            cout << "enter number of copies to add to cart \n" ; cin >> num_of_copies;
            string order = cname+"order";
            cartitem x;
            x.name = bname;
            x.num_of_copies=num_of_copies;
            if(customersdata.is_open()){
               string b;
               while (getline(customersdata,b)){
                     if (b.find(order, 0) != string::npos){
                         size_t pos;
                         pos = b.find(order, 0);
                         customersdata.seekp(pos+ci);
                         customersdata << "item" << ci << ": " << x.name << " num of copies: " << x.num_of_copies <<'\n';}}}
            else { cout << "unable to open file\n";}}

        int main(){  
            string cname;
            customersdata.open("customersdata.txt", ios::out | ios::in);
            cout << "enter customer name\n";   cin >> cname;
            newcustomer(customersdata,cname);
            addtocart(customersdata,cname);
            customersdata.close();
            string filename = "customersdata.txt";
            system(filename.c_str());}
```

[that's what the file looks like if I run a test code for a person named james](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQeu2.png)

Comment: Once you have open the `customersdata` stream and added the customer name, you need to seek back to begining of the stream otherwise `addtocart` function will never find the customer name

Comment: check for `seekp` and `tellp` function. I am not sure but also take a peek on `flush` function.